# How remove main table in database in wordpress without losing wordpress site?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

How can I remove one table from wordpress tables without losing wordpress site?

I mean the main tables, not the plugin tables.

For example, the comment table or post table - if I remove it from phpmyadmin and then go back to the wordpress site it shows me an error and starts repairing the database. I want to be able to delete for example the comment table or option table or the main table without losing the wordpress site. I want just the user table in the wordpress site, and want to remove the other tables.

How I can edit wordpress core files that don't check the database table or just check if the user table exists?
Thanks.
Best regards

Comment: You can't. Wordpress depends on those tables, and that's where all of the settings and content lives. If you want something less database driven, use something else.

Comment: I want to use the wordpress login and register on external php site and the wordpress login and all sessions is secure

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, WordPress requires all the tables that it creates, even if it doesn't seem like it is using them. You can absolutely build a system that only uses WordPress for authentication and/or authorization (I've built several), but you must accept that the other tables and **all** of the core code exists.

If instead you just want a secure login and session, I would encourage you to look at a library such as [PHP-Auth](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth) or even better, [Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html#gsc.tab=0). With the latter you can very easy get an authentication and authorization in place and then move on to your code.

However, if you are dead-set on using WordPress, and you are willing to accept that the other tables must exist even if you aren't using them, [here's some code](https://github.com/vendi-advertising/vendi-template-router) that we've used successfully on many sites. The documentation is pretty good but generally it relies on overriding WordPress's action for `template_include` which allows you to run whatever file/code you want. We almost always pair that code with [this theme](https://github.com/vendi-advertising/vendi-template-router-shared-theme) whose sole purpose is to force users to login before doing anything.

Explaining everything in there is out of scope for this site, and I would very much encourage you to **not use it** unless you have a very specific need that cannot be satisfied by using a third-party library.